# List all the tags using input (Jenkinsfile)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to list all the tags (GitLab) inside an input choise, but I do not know how to do it.

What I want to do is to be able to select the tag and based on that perform the deploy to different environments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I proposes such a solution working in declarative pipeline with dsl:

1. stage with download repo
2. parse tags based on repo
3. stage with choice parameter

CODE:

```
pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {

        stage('PollSCM') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'repo']]])
                script {
                    tags = sh(script: "git tag --sort=v:refname | tail -5 ", returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('CHOICE TAG') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def tag_response = input message: 'blah blah tags',
                            parameters: [choice(choices: "${tags}",  description: 'blah', name: '')]
                    env.tag_response = tag_response
                }

            }
        }

        stage ('echo choose') {
            steps {
                echo "I choose: '${tag_response}'"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius, teacher, idol, god hahaha, really thank you very much, I've been trying to do that for two days. It is possible that you give me your mail to ask you something: D

Comment: you can give me ur linkedin for more help @BastiánSN

Answer (score 0):

There's actually another syntax to get the list of branches/tags inside your parameters using the `git-parameter` plugin  (already provided by Git Plugin and Git Client Plugin), version 0.9.4 or greater:

```bash
    pipeline {

        agent any

        parameters{

            gitParameter name: 'TAG_OR_BRANCH',
                         type: 'PT_BRANCH_TAG',
                         defaultValue: 'master'
        }

        stages {
            stage('Checkout') {
                steps {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${params.TAG_OR_BRANCH}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin.git']] ])
                }
            }
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    script {
                            // Here you can also use a regex to match a pattern, 1.x.x-ALPHA, BETA etc.
                            if (("${params.TAG_OR_BRANCH}" == "master")){
                                echo "Do something from master branch"
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above example will list the branches and tags and the selected choice will be held inside variable `${params.TAG_OR_BRANCH}`, but you can also list branches only, tags only etc. by using the corresponding option for `type:`

- PT_TAG
- PT_BRANCH
- PT_BRANCH_TAG
- PT_REVISION
- PT_PULL_REQUEST

This also works  with GUI checkout SCM, ie you can remove the checkout stage in the above example and just use `${params.TAG_OR_BRANCH}` when asked for the branch name on jenkins GUI.

see [git-parameter doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/) for more.